# AMOS-like diagrams in R

Tags: r, r-lavaan, semplot, amos

I am doing an SEM analysis in R using `lavaan`. My analysis is complete, but I am not satisfied with the diagrams of the measurement model and structural model provided by `semPlot` and `lavaanPlot`. In `lavaanPlot`, the path arrows are curly, giving a hand-drawn impression, in `semPlot`, the variables and paths are a bit cluttered.

Is it possible to mimic diagrams produced by AMOS in R (not necessarily the colours etc. But at least the overall structure)? I tried using `semPlotModel_AMOS(model.fit)` (here `model.fit` is the object I got by fitting my SEM model to data).

But it throws an error,

`Error in file.info(object) : invalid filename argument`

`In addition: Warning message:`

`In semPlotModel_Amos(model3.fit) :`

`(Residual) variances of Amos model is not yet supported`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `Onyx` package](https://github.com/brandmaier/onyxR) to build a `lavaan` (or `OpenMx`) model starting with the path diagram, similar to how Amos works.  I think [the WebSEM site](https://websem.psychstat.org/login.php) still provides similar functionality if you want to fit your model using a web interface.

To automatically design a graphic from a fitted `lavaan` model, I am unaware of options other than the `semPlot` and `lavaanPlot` packages you already mentioned.  But you could fairly easily build your own custom path diagram using [the `DiagrammeR` package](https://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/graphviz_and_mermaid.html) (see their video demonstration).  Unfortunately, there must always be a trade-off between ease-of-use/automation and flexibility/control to get exactly the picture you want.